# Dspace 7.4 authentication with LDAP Active Directory

Tags: ldap

Could you suggest step by step how to enable authorization through Active Directory in repository Dspace 7.4?

Repository Dspace 7.4 installed in virtual Ubuntu server. Active directory in Windows server. How to authorize university employees in Dspace via Active directory? How to make sure that employees can log in to a website installed in Ubuntu server through Active directory? Has anyone tried this with Dspace? Can you please describe step by step how to do it? What needs to be installed on an Ubuntu server to link a website to Active Directory? I am new to using Ubuntu server, so can you describe the process in detail?

I found the following instructions https://www.techsupportpk.com/2021/03/integrating-active-directory-authentication-apache-ubuntu.html. But I have a virtual host, not a local one. My config files:

**server:** Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu 20.04),
**dspaceVersion:** "DSpace 7.5-SNAPSHOT",
**tomcat config files:** /etc/tomcat9/server.xml

```
<Connector address="127.0.0.1" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"
               minSpareThreads="25"
               enableLookups="false"
               disableUploadTimeout="true"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

**apache2 config files:** /etc/apache2/sites-available/dspace.conf

```
     <VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerName myRepository.myUniversity.domain
         Redirect / https://myRepository.myUniversity.domain
     </VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName myRepository.myUniversity.domain
     LogLevel warn
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myRepository.myUniversity.domain.error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myRepository.myUniversity.domain.access.log combined
     ProxyRequests on
     SSLEngine on
     SLProxyEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/STAR_myUniversity_com.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/STAR_myUniversity_com.key
     SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/SectigoCA.crt
     SSLCompression off
     SSLProtocol             all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
     SSLCipherSuite `ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-           AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20- POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384`
     SSLHonorCipherOrder     off
     SSLSessionTickets       off
     ProxyPreserveHost on
     RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https

 <Proxy *>
     AddDefaultCharset Off
     Require all granted
 </Proxy>

     ProxyPass /server http://localhost:8080/server
     ProxyPassReverse /server http://localhost:8080/server
     ProxyPass / http://localhost:4000/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4000/

 </VirtualHost>
```

I apologize if my question sounded rude or if I made mistakes. I speak English very badly, so I use google translator. I would be grateful if you could help with the difficulties I am having.